# Gradle Java compilation error using pattern matching instanceof & switch expressions

Tags: java, gradle, compiler-errors, compilation, minecraft

I am getting the following error when compiling my Gradle Java project:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\CommandsManager.java:52: error: ')' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\CommandsManager.java:52: error: not a statement
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                 ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\CommandsManager.java:52: error: ';' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                       ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\CommandsManager.java:56: error: 'else' without 'if'
                    } else
                      ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:38: error: ')' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:38: error: not a statement
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                 ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:38: error: ';' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                       ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:54: error: 'else' without 'if'
                    } else
                      ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:66: error: ')' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:66: error: not a statement
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                 ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:66: error: ';' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                       ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:72: error: 'else' without 'if'
                    } else
                      ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:81: error: ')' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:81: error: not a statement
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                 ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:81: error: ';' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                       ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:84: error: 'else' without 'if'
                    } else
                      ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:93: error: ')' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:93: error: not a statement
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                 ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:93: error: ';' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                       ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:96: error: 'else' without 'if'
                    } else
                      ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:107: error: ')' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:107: error: not a statement
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                 ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:107: error: ';' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                       ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:110: error: ')' expected
                        if (recipe instanceof FurnaceBuilder furnace) {
                                                            ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:110: error: not a statement
                        if (recipe instanceof FurnaceBuilder furnace) {
                                                             ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:110: error: ';' expected
                        if (recipe instanceof FurnaceBuilder furnace) {
                                                                    ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:115: error: 'else' without 'if'
                    } else
                      ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:125: error: ')' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:125: error: not a statement
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                 ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:125: error: ';' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                       ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RecipesCommand.java:133: error: 'else' without 'if'
                    } else
                      ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:23: error: : expected
                        case "ITEMS" -> reloadItems(sender);
                                    ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:23: error: illegal start of expression
                        case "ITEMS" -> reloadItems(sender);
                                     ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:23: error: ';' expected
                        case "ITEMS" -> reloadItems(sender);
                                                   ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:23: error: not a statement
                        case "ITEMS" -> reloadItems(sender);
                                                    ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:23: error: ';' expected
                        case "ITEMS" -> reloadItems(sender);
                                                          ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:24: error: : expected
                        case "PACK" -> reloadPack(OraxenPlugin.get(), sender);
                                   ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:24: error: illegal start of expression
                        case "PACK" -> reloadPack(OraxenPlugin.get(), sender);
                                    ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:24: error: ';' expected
                        case "PACK" -> reloadPack(OraxenPlugin.get(), sender);
                                                 ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:24: error: ';' expected
                        case "PACK" -> reloadPack(OraxenPlugin.get(), sender);
                                                                    ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:24: error: not a statement
                        case "PACK" -> reloadPack(OraxenPlugin.get(), sender);
                                                                      ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:24: error: ';' expected
                        case "PACK" -> reloadPack(OraxenPlugin.get(), sender);
                                                                            ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:25: error: : expected
                        case "RECIPES" -> RecipesManager.reload(OraxenPlugin.get());
                                      ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:25: error: illegal start of expression
                        case "RECIPES" -> RecipesManager.reload(OraxenPlugin.get());
                                       ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:25: error: ';' expected
                        case "RECIPES" -> RecipesManager.reload(OraxenPlugin.get());
                                                        ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:26: error: : expected
                        case "CONFIGS" -> OraxenPlugin.get().reloadConfigs();
                                      ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:26: error: illegal start of expression
                        case "CONFIGS" -> OraxenPlugin.get().reloadConfigs();
                                       ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:26: error: ';' expected
                        case "CONFIGS" -> OraxenPlugin.get().reloadConfigs();
                                                      ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:27: error: : expected
                        default -> {
                               ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:27: error: illegal start of expression
                        default -> {
                                ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:27: error: ';' expected
                        default -> {
                                  ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:34: error: ')' expected
                    }
                     ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\ReloadCommand.java:35: error: illegal start of expression
                });
                 ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RepairCommand.java:27: error: ')' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RepairCommand.java:27: error: not a statement
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                 ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RepairCommand.java:27: error: ';' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                       ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RepairCommand.java:55: error: 'else' without 'if'
                    } else {
                      ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RepairCommand.java:65: error: ')' expected
        if (!(itemMeta instanceof Damageable damageable))
                                            ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RepairCommand.java:65: error: illegal start of expression
        if (!(itemMeta instanceof Damageable damageable))
                                                       ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\RepairCommand.java:65: error: ';' expected
        if (!(itemMeta instanceof Damageable damageable))
                                                        ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\font\Glyph.java:8: error: class, interface, or enum expected
public record Glyph(String name, char character, String texture, int ascent,
       ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\font\Glyph.java:11: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    public JsonObject toJson() {
           ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\font\Glyph.java:13: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        JsonArray chars = new JsonArray();
        ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\font\Glyph.java:14: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        chars.add(String.valueOf(character));
        ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\font\Glyph.java:15: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        output.add("chars", chars);
        ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\font\Glyph.java:16: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        output.addProperty("file", texture);
        ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\font\Glyph.java:17: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        output.addProperty("ascent", 8);
        ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\font\Glyph.java:18: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        output.addProperty("height", height);
        ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\font\Glyph.java:19: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        output.addProperty("type", "bitmap");
        ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\font\Glyph.java:20: error: class, interface, or enum expected
        return output;
        ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\font\Glyph.java:21: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    }
    ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\font\Glyph.java:23: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    public boolean hasPermission(Player player) {
           ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\font\Glyph.java:25: error: class, interface, or enum expected
    }
    ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:71: error: ')' expected
        if (itemMeta instanceof PotionMeta potionMeta) {
                                          ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:71: error: not a statement
        if (itemMeta instanceof PotionMeta potionMeta) {
                                           ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:71: error: ';' expected
        if (itemMeta instanceof PotionMeta potionMeta) {
                                                     ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:80: error: ')' expected
        if (itemMeta instanceof TropicalFishBucketMeta tropicalFishBucketMeta) {
                                                      ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:80: error: not a statement
        if (itemMeta instanceof TropicalFishBucketMeta tropicalFishBucketMeta) {
                                                       ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:80: error: ';' expected
        if (itemMeta instanceof TropicalFishBucketMeta tropicalFishBucketMeta) {
                                                                             ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:280: error: ')' expected
        if (itemMeta instanceof Damageable damageable) {
                                          ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:280: error: not a statement
        if (itemMeta instanceof Damageable damageable) {
                                           ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:280: error: ';' expected
        if (itemMeta instanceof Damageable damageable) {
                                                     ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:287: error: ')' expected
        if (itemMeta instanceof LeatherArmorMeta leatherArmorMeta) {
                                                ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:287: error: not a statement
        if (itemMeta instanceof LeatherArmorMeta leatherArmorMeta) {
                                                 ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:287: error: ';' expected
        if (itemMeta instanceof LeatherArmorMeta leatherArmorMeta) {
                                                                 ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:294: error: ')' expected
        if (itemMeta instanceof PotionMeta potionMeta) {
                                          ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:294: error: not a statement
        if (itemMeta instanceof PotionMeta potionMeta) {
                                           ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:294: error: ';' expected
        if (itemMeta instanceof PotionMeta potionMeta) {
                                                     ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:309: error: ')' expected
        if (itemMeta instanceof SkullMeta skullMeta) {
                                         ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:309: error: not a statement
        if (itemMeta instanceof SkullMeta skullMeta) {
                                          ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:309: error: ';' expected
        if (itemMeta instanceof SkullMeta skullMeta) {
                                                   ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:317: error: ')' expected
        if (itemMeta instanceof TropicalFishBucketMeta tropicalFishBucketMeta) {
                                                      ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:317: error: not a statement
        if (itemMeta instanceof TropicalFishBucketMeta tropicalFishBucketMeta) {
                                                       ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\items\ItemBuilder.java:317: error: ';' expected
        if (itemMeta instanceof TropicalFishBucketMeta tropicalFishBucketMeta) {
                                                                             ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\mechanics\provided\custom\CustomMechanicAction.java:17: error: illegal start of expression
            CustomAction action = switch (params[0]) {
                                  ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\mechanics\provided\custom\CustomMechanicAction.java:17: error: not a statement
            CustomAction action = switch (params[0]) {
                                         ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\mechanics\provided\custom\CustomMechanicAction.java:17: error: ';' expected
            CustomAction action = switch (params[0]) {
                                                    ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\mechanics\provided\custom\CustomMechanicAction.java:18: error: orphaned case
                case "command" -> new CommandAction(params);
                ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\mechanics\provided\custom\CustomMechanicAction.java:18: error: : expected
                case "command" -> new CommandAction(params);
                              ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\mechanics\provided\custom\CustomMechanicAction.java:18: error: illegal start of expression
                case "command" -> new CommandAction(params);
                               ^
100 errors
 
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
 
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
 
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
 
BUILD FAILED in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
```

Comment: Part of those 100 errors would probably be more useful in understanding what's wrong. Start with a couple from the top, for example.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Nrjje3Dn complete error

Comment: Also please don't post text as images but post the text itself (nicely formatted of course to make it readable). And don't post links to code or text as those can break and other users might be wary of following them (or can't due to firewall rules). Do yourself a favor and put some effort into the question.

Comment: Looks like this is using features from a java version that is higher than the one you're using.

Comment: @Universefilatov: please don't use external links or images instead of updating your question to contain the relevant error messages. Edit your question to contain them instead. And if there are too many error messages for that, then just post the first few (like 10). It's unlikely that anyone's going to read all of them anyway. [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: I strongly suspect that @FedericoklezCulloca is absolutely correct.  The compilation failure is due to a [pattern matching `instanceof` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html) not being recognized by the compiler.  This feature was not added to the Java language until Java 16.  I'm guessing the project's `build.gradle` isn't enforcing that version of Java, so it uses whatever version you're running the build as.  What version of Java are you using?  What do you get when you run `java --version`?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], including a build.gradle script, and specify the Java version you're using.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be due to an older version of Java being used to compile the code, when at least Java 16 must be used.  Using a new enough version of Java should fix this particular issue.

The compiler output is failing on some newer Java features: the [pattern matching `instanceof` operator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/language/pattern-matching-instanceof-operator.html) added in Java 16, and [switch expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/language/switch-expressions.html) added in Java 14.

```
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\commands\CommandsManager.java:52: error: ')' expected
                    if (sender instanceof Player player) {
                                                ^
```

```
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\mechanics\provided\custom\CustomMechanicAction.java:17: error: ';' expected
            CustomAction action = switch (params[0]) {
                                                    ^
D:\compilar\Oraxen-master\src\main\java\io\th0rgal\oraxen\mechanics\provided\custom\CustomMechanicAction.java:18: error: orphaned case
                case "command" -> new CommandAction(params);
                ^
```

Given that the failures are due to newer language features, this tells me that the issue is likely due to an older version of Java being used (Java 13 or earlier).

There are two ways to address this.  The first (and less portable) way is to ensure the build is running under a new enough version of Java.  For instance, when run under the command line, the `java --version` should indicate Java version of at least 16 before running the build.  If the version is too old, a newer version must be installed first.

The second approach is to specify the version of Java to be used within the Gradle build.  This will ensure that the build is always used with the correct version of Java.  With newer versions of Gradle, the [Java Toolchain](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/toolchains.html) can be configured to use the proper version:

```groovy
java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(16)
    }
}
```